# Calculate non-fixed days loop from start date for roaster

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

As a part of my employees project, I have a schedule routine for the crews/shifts of work. I wonder what is the best way to examine today state (work or day off) if I'm working over a non fixed pattern of work days like so: let's say start date of roaster is 1 Jan 2018 and the pattern is: first day is morning shift (1 Jan: from 6 am to 14 pm) then second day is afternoon shift (2 Jan: from 14 pm to 10 pm) then third day is night overlap shift (3 Jan: 10 pm to 4 Jan 10 am) then forth and fifth days (4 Jan and 5 Jan) are days off, and after that it all start over again form 6 Jan as a morning shift and so on. So as you see it's not related to days of week (as usual) so my variables is the start date and the pattern. What is the best approach to do it?

Comment: How about computing (the number of days between query date and start date) mod the pattern length, and that gives you the sub day of the pattern?

Comment: I'd write it on a whiteboard, stare at it for a few hours and try to see the pattern for myself.

Comment: @NetMage that's already what I'm confused about, i already know that pattern as I explained in my question but what I want to achieve is how I will calculate it over dates and not over days of week basis.

Comment: @Milster again, I already know the pattern. But how - for an example - I know that today (25 Jun) is work or day off if the schedule start date is (1 Jan) over the pattern I mentioned in my question?

Comment: It's the 176th day of the year. (177 in a leap year). 176 mod 5 equals 1. So it's the second day of work (0 based index), an afternoon shift. Does that help you to get an idea?

Comment: @Milster yeah that's a wonderful start.. I can see your point and it's completely right, but what if the start date is not fixed or will not always be the start of the year? let's say i want to come up with a function that when I give a variables like: start date, pattern and query date, to get the result as a state of that query date?

Comment: Get the difference between your target date and your initial scheduling date. After that you can use the said mod operator.

Comment: @Milster so according to your approach, I should sub start date from query date using date difference calculations and then use the mod operator to get the remaining day to figure out the state of query date? It looks promising. Please post an answer with a prototype function so I can mark it and give you credit. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completion I'd like to provide the following class based approach:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var shiftScheduler = new ShiftScheduler(new DateTime(2018, 01, 01));
        var requestedShift = shiftScheduler.GetShift(new DateTime(2018, 01, 05));

        Console.WriteLine(requestedShift.IsWorkDay
          ? $"Scheduled from ${requestedShift.HoursBegin}{requestedShift.MinutesBegin:00} " +
            $"to {requestedShift.HoursEnd}{requestedShift.MinutesEnd:00}"
          : "No work today");
    }

}

public class Shift
{
    public Shift(int hoursBegin, int hoursEnd, int minutesBegin, int minutesEnd, bool isWorkDay)
    {
        HoursBegin = hoursBegin;
        HoursEnd = hoursEnd;
        MinutesBegin = minutesBegin;
        MinutesEnd = minutesEnd;
        IsWorkDay = isWorkDay;
    }

    public int HoursBegin { get; set; }
    public int HoursEnd { get; set; }
    public int MinutesBegin { get; set; }
    public int MinutesEnd { get; set; }
    public bool IsWorkDay { get; set; }
}

public class ShiftScheduler
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, Shift> _shifts = new Dictionary<int, Shift>();
    private readonly DateTime _startDate;

    public ShiftScheduler(DateTime startDate)
    {
        Initialize();
        _startDate = startDate;
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        _shifts.Add(0, new Shift(6, 14, 0, 0, true)); // Day 1
        _shifts.Add(1, new Shift(14, 22, 0, 0, true)); // Day 2
        _shifts.Add(2, new Shift(22, 6, 0, 0, true)); // Day 3
        _shifts.Add(3, new Shift(0, 0, 0, 0, false)); // Day 4, day off
        _shifts.Add(4, new Shift(0, 0, 0, 0, false)); // Day 5, day off
    }

    public Shift GetShift(DateTime targetDate)
    {
        int days = (int)Math.Floor((targetDate - _startDate).TotalDays);
        if (days < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Target date prior to start date.");
        }

        Shift targetShift;
        _shifts.TryGetValue(days % _shifts.Count, out targetShift);
        return targetShift;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a way better answer and completely satisfy my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample function that calculates the state for a date:

```
void Main() {
    var workPattern = new List<DayState> { DayState.MorningShift, DayState.AfternoonShift, DayState.NightShift, DayState.OffDay, DayState.OffDay };
    var startDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1);

    var queryDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 4);
    Console.WriteLine($"{queryDate:d} is {StateOfDate(startDate, workPattern, queryDate)}");

    queryDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 21);
    Console.WriteLine($"{queryDate:d} is {StateOfDate(startDate, workPattern, queryDate)}");

    queryDate = new DateTime(2018, 2, 6);
    Console.WriteLine($"{queryDate:d} is {StateOfDate(startDate, workPattern, queryDate)}");

    queryDate = new DateTime(2018, 3, 4);
    Console.WriteLine($"{queryDate:d} is {StateOfDate(startDate, workPattern, queryDate)}");
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public enum DayState {
    MorningShift, AfternoonShift, NightShift, OffDay
};

public DayState StateOfDate(DateTime startDate, List<DayState> workPattern, DateTime queryDate) {
    var numDays = Math.Floor((queryDate-startDate).TotalDays);
    var patternOffset = ((int)numDays) % workPattern.Count;
    return workPattern[patternOffset];
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I had a different idea in mind, but this one is short and efficient.

Comment: @Milster Thanks. Obviously a work pattern should really be a class that encapsulates the start date and `DayState` pattern and has a method to compute the state for a day.

Answer (score 0):

How About This : 
Ps : if u don't like setting the IsOff flag from the constructor you should set it as a set Method of the Date property

```
public Class WorkDay
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public ShiftType ShiftType { get; set; }
    public bool IsOff { get; set;}
    public string HolidayName { get; set; }

    public WorkDay(DateTime date)
    {
          Date = date;
          if (date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday )
          IsOff = true;
    } 
}



enum ShiftType 
{
   Morning, Mid , Night
}
```

Comment: That assumes a 7day (5work, 2 off) schedule. We have a 3work, 2off schedule here.

Comment: i am just modeling you business , not writing logic , you can delegate the SetDayOff() functionality to a specific algorithm , it won't be hard if ur days off are fixed (you always know which days gonna be off) , if its gonna be a rotational days off then the system can't predict it , u need to design out offline then insert it in the WorkDays Table  , or you can write an algorithm that  generates this rotation for you in respect to some conditions

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's completely off point sorry! This class will be good for a days of week fixed pattern, but not my mentioned pattern. I work on dates pattern as @Milster said.

Comment: as i said , this class's is main propose is modeling ur business making it easier to filter days , know which days are off and generate desired reports  , but if u want a function for setting off days  we need to know what are ur rules for ur shift schedules